# My Python Web Scraping code works completely but my last print doesn't produce a result?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to learn python and have started getting a hang of it, I am studying through Harvard course. This was the first course. I got most of the correction by myself and through search. The only thing I'm getting stuck at is the last print statement doesn't run. It produces 0. Also it runs correctly when I run through the command line but in python 3.5 the code produces error

> IndentationError: Unexpected indent: job_links.append(base_url + '/rc/clk?jk=' #+ id)

This is my result

> C:\Users\Vishrut\Desktop\Python Practice Codes>python
>   Jobs_Indeed_Python.py 
>   Search yielded 23,149 hits. 
>   23149 
>   2315 
>   2305 
>   We found a lot of jobs:  0:

```
import urllib.request
import bs4
import numpy as np
# Fixed url for job postings containing data scientist
url = 'http://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=data+scientist&l='
# read the website
source = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
new_source = source.decode('UTF-8')
# parse html code
bs_tree = bs4.BeautifulSoup(new_source,"html.parser")
job_count_string = bs_tree.find(id = 'searchCount').contents[0]
job_count_string = job_count_string.split()[-1]
print("Search yielded %s hits." % (job_count_string))

# not that job_count so far is still a string, 
# not an integer, and the , separator prevents 
# us from just casting it to int

job_count_digits = [int(d) for d in job_count_string if d.isdigit()]
job_count = np.sum([digit*(10**exponent) for digit, exponent in 
                    zip(job_count_digits[::-1], 
range(len(job_count_digits)))])

print (job_count)
num_pages = int(np.ceil(job_count/10.0))
base_url = 'http://www.indeed.com'
job_links = []
for i in range(20):
    if i%10 == 0:
        print(num_pages-i)
        url = 'http://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=data+scientist&start=' + 
        str(i*10)
        html_page = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
        bs_tree = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html_page,"html.parser")
        job_link_area = bs_tree.find(id = 'resultsCol')
        job_postings = job_link_area.findAll("div")
        job_postings = [jp for jp in job_postings if not jp.get('class') is 
        None and  not jp.get('div') is None and ''.join(jp.get('class')) == 
        "rowresult"]
        job_ids = [jp.get('data-jk') for jp in job_postings]
    for id in job_ids:
        job_links.append(base_url + '/rc/clk?jk=' + id)

print ("We found a lot of jobs: \n", len(job_links))
```

Comment: hi Micah, Thanks for your response.I brought it inside the loop but it still produces 0 for the last print statement.

Answer (score 0):

Highlight these two lines:

```
for id in job_ids:
    job_links.append(base_url + '/rc/clk?jk=' + id)
```

And hit tab.

Those two lines can't see the data produced above them because in Python's view, those two lines are not in the same loop.  They just need to be tabbed over.

Answer (score 0):

So I tried to debug my code by printing job id's and it was producing empty result set. The statement "and  not jp.get('div') is None"  was the reason for empty result set. When I removed it, it gave me the result but in future if an NoneType Error arises I will have to deal with that too.